# UploadFromStreamAsync Cancellation Token not working

Tags: c#, upload, azure-blob-storage, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

**Expected behaviour**:

Looking at my internet usage in task manager after running should see a spike in upload for around 5 seconds and then a drop back to normal levels.

**Result**:

Upload speed spikes for a lot longer (closer to a minute or more, indicative of the full file being uploaded)

**Tried**:

- Cancelling after multiple times (e.g. 1 second, 10 seconds etc)
- Immediately cancelling with the token after starting the upload Using
- UploadFromByteArrayAsync() instead of UploadFromStreamAsync()  Using
- BeginUploadFromStream() with EndUploadFromStream()

Although I can quite easily cancel a download using the CancellationToken, no matter what I do, I can't cancel this upload. Also, weirdly, searching online, I can't find any instance of anyone else having problems cancelling an upload.

```
            _connectionString = "xxx";                

            if (_connectionString != "")
            {
                _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString);
                _blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            }

            string ulContainerName = "speedtest";
            string ulBlobName = "uploadTestFile" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();

            CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(ulContainerName);
            CloudBlockBlob ulBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(ulBlobName);

            CreateDummyDataAsync(_fileUploadSizeMB);

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_filePath + "dummy_upload");

            ulBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream(byteArray), _ulCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            _ulCancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(5000);
```

Comment: You're not `await`ing your call to `UploadFromStreamAsync`

Comment: Doing something like 

```Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await ulBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream(byteArray), _ulCancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    _ulCancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(5000);
                });```

Will have the upload method run entirely before hitting the CancelAfter(5000) line. Unless there's another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone that ends up in this situation and can't get the cancellationToken to work... the workaround I eventually used was

```
            BlobRequestOptions timeoutRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            // Allot 10 seconds for this API call, including retries
            MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
```

Then include the timeoutRequestOptions in the method arguments:

```
ulBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream(byteArray), new AccessCondition(),
                                                   timeoutRequestOptions,
                                                   new OperationContext(),
                                                   new progressHandler(), cancellationToken.Token);
```

This will force the API call to timeout after a certain time.